# ReactJS: CSS width different from what set for component

Tags: css, reactjs

See below screenshot. `width` is different, though other attributes remain the same. React 15.3.1 with material-ui 0.16.1. Same on Chrome, Safari and Firefox, so it's unlikely to be a browser relevant issue.

[image: elements-vs-react]

Comment: Could you please reproduce the code within your answer?

Comment: Thanks. I'll try but it would take some time as the code is deeply under https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/v0.16.1/src/DropDownMenu/DropDownMenu.js.

Comment: And if you would provide issued code, we could help you. :)